# SQLiteConnection.Open keeps blocking if pooling enabled

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm using `System.Data.SQLite` (v1.0.104) in a multi-threaded C# application. When a thread want's to update the DB, it opens a new connection in a `using` statement (calling the method below) and executes its queries. This seems to work well with the connection string in the following example:

```c#
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
private SQLiteConnection CreateSQLiteConnection()
{
    var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=myDatabase.sqlite;Version=3");
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

However if I add `Pooling=True` to the connection string, I can observe the following: One thread is blocking on `connection.Open();` indefinitely while the other threads are waiting to enter `CreateSQLiteConnection`. As far as I can tell from the debugger, at this point in time no thread is actually performing any kind of update to the db.

I already tried setting busy and default timeouts but that didn't change anything. I also know that the sqlite documentation suggests to avoid multiple threads altogether but that is currently not an option.

I've added the `Synchronized` attribute to avoid potential issues regarding multiple threads simultaneously calling `SQLiteConnection.Open` but it did not seem to make a difference.

Does anyone know what might cause `SQLiteConnection.Open` to behave like that or what I could try to get more details about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite Version 3 ==> .s3db,

```
public SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=E:\Foldername\myDatabase.s3db;");
 SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
            cnn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Tble_UserSetUp";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
            mycommand.CommandText = sql;
 SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = mycommand;
            da.Fill(ds);
 cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for you're suggestion, but i actually _am_ using sqlite version 3.11 (as you can see in the connection string). 1.0.104 is just the version if the C# connector.

Comment: You can just update the connector by this NuGet console: 'PM> Install-Package System.Data.SQLite' in Visual Studio.

Comment: 1.0.104 is the latest version

Comment: just try to execute once more NuGet console code and then try to Open SQLite using above code.

Comment: Is the DB located in your local disc? and Are you sure, your DB extension is .s3db ?

Comment: Yes, it is on my disk and yes, the db file extension is `s3db`